# About the Kähler potential of Calabi–Yau 3-fold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Background:

In Calabi-Yau 3-fold, the Kähler metric is given in terms of the Kähler potential $\kappa$ :

$$ g_{i\bar{j}} = \partial_i \partial_{\bar{j}} \kappa,$$

where $i, \bar{j} = 1,2,3 $ ( the Holomorphic coordinates) . While the complex structure metric is given by:

$$ G_{a\bar{b}} = \partial_a \partial_{\bar{b}} \kappa,$$

where $ a, \bar{b} = 1, …, h_{2,1} $, where $ h_{2,1} $ is the number of complex structure moduli.

See for instance [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4847). The Question:

- first if I in 5d, $N=2$ supergravity, for instance, (after dimensional reduction from 11d SUGRA), can I find an explicit form for the Kähler potential?
- Can I after that calculate $G_{a\bar{b}}$ and $ g_{i\bar{j}}$? And what about the degrees of freedom?

I mean for example, $N=1$, $D= 4$, SUGRA. See for instance: In [this paper](https://pos.sissa.it/001/011/pdf), the Kähler potential is given by

$$ \kappa = \phi_i \phi^{i *} $$

and the Kähler metric is given by:

$$ g_{i j^*} = \frac{\partial^2 \kappa}{\partial \phi_i \partial \phi_{j^*}},$$

where $\phi_i$ are scalar fields.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you can find an explicit expression of the Kahler potential, then you find explicit representation of the metric. I doubt if that can be done.

Comment: What about ( Fubini–Study) ? a Kähler potential was assumed on $\bf CP^n$ ?

Comment: @ArcticChar , that what I exactly wonder about,  if you know something like Fubini–Study metric.

Comment: Yes you can do it for Fubini Study metric on $\mathbb{CP}^n$, and probably some other metric on toric manifolds. But even for quintic I doubt if there is an explicit form (the restriction of the Fubini-Study metric from $\mathbb{CP}^4$ to the quintic is not CY).

Comment: I’m still new in that, but it’s known quintic manifold is Calabi–Yau 3-fold, i.e., CY in 3 complex dimensions!